# C# - TLS / SSL Websockets using fleck

Tags: c#, ssl, websocket

Im trying to make a TLS/SSL websocket connection using Fleck lib.

> https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck  (0.9.8.25)

now i got the server startet .
but when a client connects  i get the following message.

> ```
> 28-02-2014 19:16:15 [Info] Server started at wss://localhost:8081
> 28-02-2014 19:18:51 [Debug] Client connected from 127.0.0.1:62543
> 28-02-2014 19:18:51 [Debug] Authenticating Secure Connection
> 28-02-2014 19:18:52 [Debug] 0 bytes read. Closing.
> ```

anybody got an idea of what im doing wrong ?

> Browser: Chrome, version : 33.0.1750.117

// sample code.

```
        FleckLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug;

        var allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();

        var server = new WebSocketServer("wss://localhost:8081");

        server.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"CRT.pfx", "Pwd");

        server.Start(socket =>
        {

            socket.OnOpen = () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Open!");
                allSockets.Add(socket);
            };
            socket.OnClose = () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Close!");
                allSockets.Remove(socket);
            };
            socket.OnMessage = message =>
            {

                foreach (var user in allSockets.ToList())
                {
                     if(user.ConnectionInfo.Id != socket.ConnectionInfo.Id){
                         user.Send(message);
                     }
                }

            };
        });


        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        while (input != "exit")
        {

            foreach (var socket in allSockets.ToList())
            {
                socket.Send(input);
            }

            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is certificate signed by a browser trusted CA? If not, the web page you are opening with Chrome has to be under HTTPS so you can be prompted to accept the certificate, otherwise the connection will fail.

If even doing that does not work, please try with [WebSocketListener](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Enabling-WebSocket-Secure-(TLS)) and tell me which error you get if any.

Some issues I found debugging WSS:

- Remember to change the port number to a one different to the one you used for not secure connections. Some browsers get confused if suddenly a port becomes secure or viceversa.
- Remember to use the hostname indicated in the certificate to connect and not the IP.
- If you are using a self-signed certificate, use it for HTTPS so you can see the dialog for accepting that certificate. When accessing via WSS:// there is not certificate acceptance dialog, it will just fail to connect.

Try with a self-signed certificate as well and see if it works.